# Access pixels with Mat OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, rgb, pixel

I would like to access pixels in RGB with OpenCV 2.3.
I'm trying like this but it's like every pixels are equal frame after frame because I got no output. Images are from my webcam and I can see them.
Btw RED = 0;

THX

```
Mat frame;
Mat oldFrame;

VideoCapture cap(0);
cap >> oldFrame;
sumFramePix = oldFrame.cols * oldFrame.rows;
nbChannels = oldFrame.channels();
cout << "NbcHANNELs : " << nbChannels << endl;
imshow("Video 1", oldFrame);

while(1)
{
    cap >> frame;
    imshow("Video 1", frame);

    for(int i=0; i<frame.rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<frame.cols; j++)
        {
            if (frame.ptr<uchar>(i)[nbChannels*j+RED] < oldFrame.ptr<uchar>(i)[nbChannels*j+RED])
            {
                cout << "==============-";
            }
        }
    }
    oldFrame = frame;

    if(waitKey(300) >= 0) break;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
oldFrame = frame;
```

to

```
oldFrame = frame.clone();
```

You are creating two Mat objects that point to the same data. `clone()` makes a deep copy.

Comment: Better use `frame.copyTo(oldFrame)` to avoid memory reallocation for each frame.