# how to append a point to another point in opencv c

Tags: c++, opencv

< I now have a binary image( Output of a Canny Detector). I want to save all the co-ordinates of the points that have a 1 into another variable called Imp_Points(defined by vector Point2f).

I tried using a for loop in the image to check for a '1' and assign those co-ordinates to the 'Imp_Points' but i was not sure how i can do this in c++.

Any suggestions on how i can do it in c++ using opencv?
Thanks in Advance! >

Comment: Consider changing topic. For example 'Extracting point coordinates from cv::Mat' or 'Extracting point coordinates from Canny output'

Answer (score 0):

**First look how to iterate over cv::Mat:**
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#mat

[Access pixels with Mat OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183359/access-pixels-with-mat-opencv)

Then you need to add coordinates to vector when pixel value is 255. Assuming you have 8 bit Canny output.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector <Point2f>Imp_Points;
for(int i=0;i<bn_img.rows;i++) {
 for(int j=0;j<bn_img.cols;j++)`{
    Point p=new Point(j,i);
    int v=bn_img<uchar>.at(p);//check the datatype of Mat here
    if(v==1)
      Imp_Points.push_back(p);
}
```